# 100mb Memory usage normal for a layout?

Tags: android, memory

i'am a little concerned about the Memory usage of my app.
For the following scenario i created a completely new Project. The MainActivity just sets the ContentView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

So... i have a simple login layout [image] [image]

which has a Memory usage of nearly 100mb!? [image]

all ImageView's dont contain any Images. They just have a static color (i.e. the light blue).

But is a memory usage of 100mb normal? Or am i missing out on something? Thank you for you're time and help!

Comment: r u loading any support libraries in your gradle?

Comment: @lib4 only the standard ones.. so: appcompat, constraint-layout and cardview

Comment: I dont think it will be a concern pls read these two links , Android uses Share Memory  https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html      https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview.html

Comment: @lib4 yeah, thank you. Just wanted to make sure its not too much

Answer (score 6):

I think it is normal. It is not eating 100MB of RAM actually. On new Android Monitor of AS3 numbers are a bit different than previous AS2. In the [user guide here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html), it is written:

> When compared to memory counts from the previous Android Monitor tool,
>   the new Memory Profiler records your memory differently, so **it might
>   seem like your memory use is now higher**. The Memory Profiler monitors
>   some extra categories that increase the total, but if you only care
>   about the Java heap memory, then the "Java" number should be similar
>   to the value from the previous tool.
>
> **And although the Java number probably doesn't exactly match what you
>   saw in Android Monitor, the new number accounts for all physical
>   memory pages that have been allocated to your app's Java heap since it
>   was forked from Zygote.** So this provides an accurate representation of
>   how much physical memory your app is actually using.
>
> Currently, **the Memory Profiler also shows some false-positive native
>   memory usage in your app that actually belongs to the profiling tools.**
>   Up to 10MB of memory is added for ~100k objects. In a future version
>   of the tools, these numbers will be filtered out of your data.